# Strange behavior when closing lid Gateway NE56R

Tags: kubuntu, acpi, lid, 14.10

I have a Gateway NE56R laptop running the latest Kubuntu 14.10 x64 beta, although I had this same problem on Trusty. This problem may also affect some Acer Aspire laptops if that helps you fix my problem.

If I close my laptop's lid (I use a VGA monitor when it's closed), my system acts a little strange. If I close it anytime between when GRUB starts booting and when I actually sign in to Kubuntu, my laptop will suspend, even though I set it not to. For this reason, my laptop DOES NOT suspend after I'm signed in. Also, closing the lid seems to significantly slow down all wireless communication via Wi-Fi (yes, I've disabled power saving).

Also, sometimes if my lid is closed for a long time (an hour maybe), all USB devices just lose power and don't work until a restart. Sometimes I can just unplug something and plug it back in and it makes everything work again. Only sometimes. Remember that; if I replug one device, it will sometimes make all devices work again. All of this also happened in Trusty too.

Also, I think I should mention that my wireless card is a Broadcom BCM4313. Although I know many, many Ubuntu users are having problems getting their BCM4313 to work, I was able to get mine to work and it works great, so don't say anything about "fixing" my wireless- it's fine. Ubuntu's reaction to the LID closing is the problem.

Comment: Come on. A bug report link? Anything? This is my computer I use every day. If someone will at least tell me information (i.e. This will be fixed in Utopic's final release), I'd appreciate it. I am just going to make a bug report, because I can't find an existing report. What package would I report this for being a bug?

Comment: Well, any debugging starts with checking logs I guess. Try closing lid just how you described, then resume the machine and go in to /var/log. Read through recent entries in boot.log, dmesg, pm-powersave.log . There's also this page here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelSuspend   . If you can't figure it out, just attach the info from the logs here, and maybe someone will figure it out .  Good luck !

Comment: Here's something else, specifically read through trace resume part. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/power/s2ram.txt

Comment: I've created a bug report at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1380144 which has many logs, which may be useful, attached. I took a guess and assumed this was a bug in Linux, so that's what the bug is against.

Comment: UPDATE: Someone changed the bug report so now it only states the WiFi slowing down. I guess that is the most important part, and the problem with USB devices could be a bug of its own. I'm going to give Linux 3.17 a try and see if that will fix it.

Comment: I know you want the bounty...

Comment: Take a look at the script in this post : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1645143  .  It's for your network card (BCM4313) and basically restarts network-manager upon resume. Also, try suspending the machine, and taking look at /var/log/pm-suspend.log

Comment: @Xieerqi I don't think that is relevant becuase my connection does not stop working entirely and my laptop does not suspend when it's closed. It's set to do nothing. Also, I tried that command and it didn't help.

Comment: That's it. I'm switching to Debian.

Comment: Have you considered that it might be the laptop's motherboard/BIOS/other hardware causing the issue? Some laptop hardware does throttle under certain conditions (eg. my Acer Aspire 5733z throttles the processors when they go above 80°C). If you have Windows installed in a duel-boot, can you test if your issues happen on there?

Comment: I have updated my EFI to the latest version, and I do infact have a Windows dual-boot. This does not happen under Windows.

Comment: It could also be a bug in my EFI, but there's nothing I can do about that. For example, I hear that many Dell laptops' fans have problems because of a bug in the BIOS and not Ubuntu. Dell users begged Dell to fix the bug. I'm not sure if they ever did release a fix, but they probably did. I'll check the Gateway forums.

Comment: Bounty ends in 3 minutes. It looks like it's a bug that may or may not have a workaround. I'm not sure if it ever will be fixed either because the kernel developer on Launchpad is starting to get lazy and hasn't said anything in like a week. This won't be fixed in time for Utopic, but maybe 15.04 has some hope, not to mention the bugfix will go into Linux instead of Ubuntu so all distributions will be able to work! It's a sad day when the Linux kernel itself has a bug that causes compatibility problems with every GNU/Linux operating system.